# How to redirect to url with injected arguments in Flask?

Tags: python, redirect, flask

I am newbie in python and flask and trying to redirect a url with headers and unable to navigate, please provide me an example to solve the issue.

```
@app.route('/somepage')
def somepage():
   headers={'SomeName':'whatever'}
   return Response(redirect(url_for('home_page')),status=302, headers=headers)

@app.route('/home_page')
def home_page():
 if request.headers['SomeName'] == 'whatever':
    return render_template("home_page.html")
 else:
     return Response(status=405)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flask [**url_for**](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.url_for) function can accept any number of ****values** you can use to send to the redirected view.

You can then use the Flask **redirect** function as so:

```
from flask import redirect
...
return redirect(url_for('home_page', headers=headers))
```

And then in the function use it as:

```
@app.route('/home_page')
def home_page():
 if json.loads(request.args.get("headers"))["SomeName"] == "whatever":
    return render_template("home_page.html")
 else:
     return Response(status=405)
```

Comment: TypeError: redirect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers' i have received this error

Comment: redirected to the page but unable to render just saying Bad Request

Comment: please explain this error ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)  at if request.args.get('headers')['SomeName'] == 'whatever':

Comment: SIngle quotes are not valid JSON, just use double quotes then.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, TypeError: string indices must be integers at  if request.args.get("headers")["SomeName"] == "whatever":

Comment: Ok, so you need to transform the json to a dictionary, I guess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150273/discussion-between-dedeepthika-and-igor).